# Как создать сырой sql-запрос во Flask-e?

Tags: sql, flask, sqlalchemy

мне кажется, эта строчка как-то связана с ним:

```
query = db.engine.execute("<SELECT * FROM Family>")
```

Такого вида запрос не интересует, это другой способ:

```
data2 = Species.query.filter(Species.kingdom_id.like(2))
```

Comment: *мне кажется, эта строчка как-то связана с ним* Не просто связана - это оно и есть. Только оно [Deprecated since version 2.0](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#connectionless-execution-implicit-execution).

Comment: @Akina, спасибо. Во кстати, тоже помогает эта информация. Надо копать здесь https://lectureswww.readthedocs.io/6.www.sync/2.codding/9.databases/2.sqlalchemy/0.engine.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось, благодаря чтению про

[engine](https://lectureswww.readthedocs.io/6.www.sync/2.codding/9.databases/2.sqlalchemy/0.engine.html#execute)

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///db.db")
 
# ... несколько таблиц БД

@app.route('/')
def func():
    query = db.engine.execute('SELECT * FROM Species WHERE kingdom_id=1')
    return render_template("index.html", query=query)


# еще надо прописать отображение фильтрованных данных в index.html.
```

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, у тебя есть таблица:  USERS(id, email, psw, date) и ты хочешь вытащить пользователя с id == 2. Тогда:

```
data = Users.query.filter_by(id=2)
```

Или если хочешь вернуть первую запись  из таблицы:

data = Users.query.first()
В обоих случая тебе вернется кортеж. Соответственно что бы вытащить что-то, ты обращаешься к полю. Например тебе надо только его email, тогда пишешь:

```
data.email
```

PS: более подробно в офиц. документации: https://flask-sqlalchemy-russian.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/queries.html

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, приму к сведению, но это другой вид запросов, не SQL.